# 3 раза ввел не правильный пароль при ssh подключении scp. Теперь не пускает на сервер

Tags: linux, ssh, vps, scp

Я пытался передать файл на сервер с помощью scp

```
scp dump.tar.gz root@mysite.ru:/
```

и не правильно ввел пароль 3 раза.
Теперь при попытке передать файл через scp вижу сообщение

```
ssh: connect to host mysite.ru port 22: 

Connection refused
lost connection
```

При этом обычное подключение по ssh все еще доступно.
Пробовал на сервере куда пытаюсь закинуть файл, очистить содержимое
/root/.ssh/known_hosts - не помогло. Пробовал разные настройки ufw на сервере, включать/отключать - так же не помогло.

Как исправить ситуацию?

P.S. Важное замечание, я пытаюсь передать с локальной машины на сервер

Comment: Я попробовал полностью заного настроить сервер. Дошел до операции scp, ввожу пароль root юзера (100% правильный. Тот же по которому получаю доступ через ssh к серверу), но в ответ Permission denied, please try again

Comment: Полагаю, что я ошибаюсь в наборе самой команды scp т.к. мне надо скопировать с локальной машины на сервер. В таком случае я должен указать сначала ip локальный, а потом удаленный. Я попробовал scp dump.tar.gz denis@127.0.0.1:. root@mysite.ru:/ и некоторые вариации, после чего меня опять заблокировало

Comment: Кажется дело в моей локальной машине. Я только что снес сервер и запустил заново, создал ssh ключ, но до сих пор при попытке передать файл через scp вижу port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
Хотя обычное  ssh подключение работает

Comment: В моём случае я имею некоторые проблемы с поставщиком услуг. Я сейчас общаюсь с тех. поддержкой, что бы узнать причину проблемы